# What is this character in this SFX?

Tags: sound-symbolism

I know the first one but the second one... I've tried to hand write it and I've thought about other characters like ク, フ and レ, researched if there's any known SFX with these combinations but nothing (apart from ビク being "biku" but I don't think that's what I'm looking for here? Or is it?

[[image: 1]]

[image: Another example of the character]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is kind of an onomatopoeia ビーッ!

Probably the 長{ちょう}音符{おんぷ} : ー zigzagged in order to imply the "lightning"-like effect of the beam from the eyes of the robot.

I guess the sound effect is similar to "beep"(high pitched sound) in English.

Does it seem to appropriate to your scene? ビク(ッ) is used when you are surprised. But this time, the robot seems to be attacking, so it does not seem to be appropriate.

Comment: So author just troll. Yeah, why didn't I think of that? Thanks for the answer and yeah Beep it is